# SQLAlchemy order by column name (not value)

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

In SQLalchemy I understand you can order by a column's values, but how can you order by the name (or reference)?

For example

```
class Users(db.Model):
    gamma = db.Column(db.Integer)
    alpha = db.Column(db.Integer)
    beta = db.Column(db.Integer)
```

I understand if I had values 1,2,3 how to order_by sort those. What about if I want

```
[alpha, beta, gamma]
```

The end goal is to put this into an OrderedDict so I can access these in the same order each time.

I have not found any documentation or stackoverflow questions that address this. Thank you

Comment: I want to consistently return results in alphabetical order so I can convert them to a vector and perform problems. So if the entries are {alpha : 2, beta : 3, gamma : 1} I can consistently convert them to [2, 3, 1] and always receive the columns by alphabetical order of the name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using base sqlalchemy you would specify the column order in the query like this

```
users = session.query(User.alpha, User.beta, User.gamma).all()
```

Using flask-sqlalchemy you need access the session through the `SQLAlchemy` object, like this:

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
...
users = db.session.query(User.alpha, User.beta, User.gamma).all()
```

In either case, each "row" in the resulting list will consist of values in the order specified inside `query(...)`

To combine retrieving objects and building the ordered dictionaries you could do this

```
from collections import OrderedDict

users = User.query.all()
data = [OrderedDict([(c.name, getattr(u, c.name)) for c in
                     sorted(u.__table__.columns, key=lambda col: col.name)])
        for u in users]
```

which sorts attributes by column name as the `OrderedDict`s are created.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand you what to put the columns into OrderedDict, why not try to sort it using **sorted()** or you can arrange your columns manually on your database models that would be easier.

```
from collections import OrderedDict
column = {1: 'gamma', 2: 'alpha', 3: 'beta'}
dict = OrderedDict(sorted(column.items(), key=lambda t: t[1]))
print(dict)
```